# Old CV no longer associated to my account

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, merge-accounts, duplicate-accounts

My cv 'https://stackoverflow.com/cv/lejenome' is no longer associated with account.

I want it to be delete so I can reuse my email & custom url on my new cv 'https://stackoverflow.com/cv/moez'.

Given:

- I tried to login with all my login credentials with no success to access to my old cv
- The e-mail associated to my old cv is associated to my stackoverflow account too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged all the data associated with the other user (with the exception of the 'lejenome' CV) into your Stack Overflow account. Your 'moez' CV is now the only one associated with your SO account.